# I have a table and I want to calculate statistics for many fields in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am a beginner with R software. I have a table with many fields (about 600). I need to compute Mean Max Min StandardDev for all the fields using a single script and saving the result into a separate file. Moreover I would like to calculate the student test of all the fields but one against the one left out.

Comment: With fields you mean columns? Look at the apply of the `apply()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Start of with this, and work your way towards your goal.
Study `apply` functions to understand.

```
#random data
dt <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100,mean = 4, sd = 2)
  ,y = rnorm(100,mean = 7, sd = 3)
  ,z = rnorm(100,mean = 5, sd = 2))
```

And
Option 1:

```
#summarize each column/field
sm <- lapply(names(dt),function(x){c(x,summary(dt[,x]))})
do.call(rbind, sm)
```

Option 2:

```
#summarize each column/field
apply(dt,2,FUN = summary)
```

With t.test:

```
lapply(names(dt),function(a){lapply(names(dt),function(b){t.test(dt[,a],dt[,b])})})
```

all comparisons combination are made. Result are in a complex list, because of all the features of the t.test.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with mean, max and SD. Only I cannot understand how to apply this for t.test. I need to apply                                                        t.test(formula = mydata$col(n) ~ mydata$col(fix))  with n that should assume all the column names while fix is always a specific column.